# Conectar base de datos SQL a un Login en Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Tengo una base de datos SQL con usuarios y contraseñas, me gustaría conectarla a visual studio pero no sé cómo conectarla ni tampoco relacionar las variables que corresponden a usuario y contraseña con los atributos correspondientes.

Lo que quiero hacer es conectar la base de datos donde están todos los usuarios y contraseñas a mi programa en Visual Studio 2017. Una vez esté conectada, me gustaría hacer uso de esos datos para que los usuarios puedan iniciar sesión, el problema es que no se como asociar el atributo usuario y contraseña (de la base de datos) a las variables usuario y contraseña que tengo declaradas en el código.

Actualmente lo tengo hecho de forma local, cosa que es una locura ya que no es nada seguro.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Pero es un proyecto web o escritorio, que tecnología estas usando?

Puedes usar un método para manejar la autenticacion

```html
public  bool Autenticar(string usuario, string password)
{
    //consulta a la base de datos
    string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario = @user AND contraseña = @pass";
    //tu cadena de conexion
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
    {
        conn.Open();//abrimos conexion
 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn); //ejecutamos la instruccion
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", usuario); //enviamos los parametros
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
 
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //devuelve la fila afectada
     
        if (count == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
 
     }
}
```

Para Implementarlo seria asi

```
if (Autenticar(txtUsuario.Text, txtClave.Text))
{
    //se autentico 

}
```

Si es proyecto Web aqui explico como hacerlo
[Inicio De Sesion Usando El Control Login Asp.Net](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2012/05/inicio-de-sesion-usando-el-control.html)

Si es una aplicacion WPF tambien aqui explico como hacerlo
[Crear Login WPF C#](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/search/label/C%20Sharp)